# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, list, generics, ienumerable

Is there any specific reason why indexing is not allowed in IEnumerable.

I found a workaround for the problem I had, but just curious to know why it does not allow indexing.

Thanks,

Comment: Sharing the code that produced the error and your workaround would be helpful.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Because it's not.

Indexing is covered by `IList`.  `IEnumerable` means "I have some of the powers of IList, but not all of them."

Some collections (like a linked list), cannot be indexed in a practical way.  But they can be accessed item-by-item.  `IEnumerable` is intended for collections like that.   Note that a collection can implement both IList & IEnumerable (and many others).  You generally only find `IEnumerable` as a function parameter, meaning the function can accept any kind of collection, because all it needs is the simplest access mode.

Comment: actually, it seems like it kind of depends. Some collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.names.aspx can be indexed.  Of course you are right that this can not be assumed from the type, which makes it all the more gross and disgusting

Comment: @nicolas: In that case, `Names` is not a class, but an interface which extends the IEnumerable interface to allow indexing, just as IList extend IEnumerable.

Comment: it must be true, as in a COM world one can new up interfaces, and ditch name convention for them, but can we really call it an interface then ?

Answer (score 66):

The [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface does not include an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), you're probably confusing it with [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)

If the object really is an `IList<T>` (e.g. `List<T>` or an array `T[]`), try making the reference to it of type `IList<T>` too.

Otherwise, you can use `myEnumerable.ElementAt(index)`  which uses the [Enumerable.ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method. This should work for all `IEnumerable<T>`s .
Note that unless the (run-time) object implements `IList<T>`, this will cause all of the first `index + 1` items to be enumerated, with all but the last being discarded.

EDIT:
As an explanation, `IEnumerable<T>` is simply an interface that represents "that which exposes an enumerator." A concrete implementation may well be some sort of in-memory list that *does* allow fast-access by index, or it may not. For instance, it could be a collection that cannot efficiently satisfy such a query, such as a linked-list (as mentioned by James Curran). It may even be *no sort* of in-memory data-structure at all, such as an iterator, where items are generated ('yielded') on demand, or by an enumerator that fetches the items from some remote data-source. Because `IEnumerable<T>` must support all these cases, indexers are excluded from its definition.

Comment: Note that since ElementAt is an extension method for IEnumerable<T>, it must walk the items one at a time to get to the item you've asked for.  It can be vary useful, but a potential performance concern.

Comment: @chilltemp: I mentioned this.

Comment: It's worth noting that the implementation of `ElementAt` is smart enough to check if the object can be cast to `IList` and if so index directly instead of doing the item-by-item walk.

Comment: myEnumerable.ElementAt(index) helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You can use **ToList** to convert to a list. For example,

```
SomeItems.ToList()[1]
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use indexing if your enumerable type is string like below

```
((string[])MyEnumerableStringList)[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

The []-operator is resolved to the access property `this[sometype index]`, with implementation depending upon the Element-*Collection*.

An Enumerable-Interface declares a blueprint *of what a Collection should look like* in the first place.

Take this example to demonstrate the usefulness of **clean Interface separation**:

```
var ienu = "13;37".Split(';').Select(int.Parse);
//provides an WhereSelectArrayIterator
var inta = "13;37".Split(';').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()[0];
//>13
//inta.GetType(): System.Int32
```

Also look at the **syntax of the []-operator**:

```
  //example
public class SomeCollection{
public SomeCollection(){}

 private bool[] bools;

  public bool this[int index] {
     get {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= bools.Length ){
           //... Out of range index Exception
        }
        return bools[index];
     }
     set {
        bools[index] = value;
     }
  }
//...
}
```

Comment: The higher-voted answers may be true, but I found this comment to be more helpful in my own scenario (which does not appear different from the original post). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One reason can be that the `IEnumerable` may contain an unknown number of items. Some implementations produce the list of items as you iterate over it (see [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx) for samples). That does not work very well with accessing items using an index. which would require you to know that there are at least that many items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of interfaces is generally to expose a sort of base line contract by which code that performs work on an object can be guaranteed of certain functionality provided by that object. In the case of `IEnumerable<T>`, that contract happens to be "you can access all of my elements one by one."

The kinds of methods that can be written based on this contract alone are many. See the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class for **tons** of examples.

But to zero in on just one concrete one: think about [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx). In order to sum up a bunch of items, what do you need? What contract would you require? The answer is quite simple: just a way to see every item, no more. Random access isn't necessary. Even a total count of all the items is not necessary.

To have added an indexer to the `IEnumerable<T>` interface would have been detrimental in two ways:

1. Code that requires the contract described above (access to a sequence of elements), if it required the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, would be artificially restrictive as it could not deal with any type that did not implement an indexer, even though to deal with such a type should really be well within the capabilities of the code.
2. Any type that wanted to expose a sequence of elements but was not appropriately equipped to provide random access by index (e.g., `LinkedList<T>`, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) would now have to either provide some inefficient means of *simulating* indexing, or else abandon the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

All this being said, considering that the purpose of an interface is to provide a guarantee of the *minimum required functionality* in a given scenario, I really think that the `IList<T>` interface is poorly designed. Or rather, the lack of [an interface "between" `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110440/why-is-there-no-iarrayt-interface-in-net) (random access, but no modification) is an unfortunate oversight in the BCL, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved it by add .ToList() at the end of LINQ statement :

```
 public ActionResult Statistics(int programId )
        {
          
            int[] testids = { 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 60, 1125, 3161 };
            var stat = (from programs_tests in _context.programs_tests
                       join labTest in _context.LabTests
                       on programs_tests.testid equals labTest.TestId
                       where programs_tests.program_id == programId
                       && !testids.Contains(labTest.TestId)
                       select programs_tests).ToList();
        
           
            return View(stat);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a column that did not allow nulls and I was inserting a null value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IEnumerable` in conjunction with `this`:

```
public interface IWorksheets : IEnumerable
{
    IWorksheet this[int index] { get; }
    IWorksheet this[string name] { get; }
}
```

Then you can use `foreach` *and* indexing:

```
IWorksheet worksheet= excelWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]

foreach (IWorksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets)
{
```