# Edit multiple instances of models asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to edit multiple (say 4) instance of my model Restriction:

```
public int RestrictionID { get; set; }
public string portefeuille { get; set; }
```

I try to do this in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Management.Models.Restriction>
@for ( int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(_ => Model.[i].portefeuille)
}
```

But I have an error that I can't use indexation on type IEnumerable.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Your model needs to be `IList`, not `IEnumerable`

Comment: and remove the `.` between `Model` and `[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code using `ILIst` because in `IEnumerable` we cant use indexation ..for using indexation you should go for `IList` + remove extra "." between `Model` and `[i]`  :-

```
 @model ILIst <Management.Models.Restriction>
 @for ( int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(_ => Model[i].portefeuille)
 }
```

For more information have a look here :-

[Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612721/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-system-collections-gener)

Comment: Thank you exactly what  I want "." between Model and [i] is a typo

Answer (score 1):

You could also use linq instead of indexing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Skip(i).Take(1).First().portefeuille)
}
```